# Prestashop returns last value of imploded array from DB

Tags: database, module, prestashop

I started fiddling with Prestashop 1.7 modules and I ran into this weird behavior.

I have this code to save values from form post to database (working ok)

```
protected function postProcess()
{
    $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

    foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
        Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));
        if($key == 'MSLT_MEGAMENU_CATEGORIES'){
            $categories = implode(",",Tools::getValue($key));
            Configuration::updateValue('MSLT_MEGAMENU_CATEGORIES', $categories);
        }else{
            $this->errors[]=$this->l('Please select categories to display');
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this code to fetch those values from database (works ok)

```
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    $categories = explode(',',Configuration::get('MSLT_MEGAMENU_CATEGORIES', true));
    return array(
        'MSLT_MEGAMENU_LIVE_MODE' => Configuration::get('MSLT_MEGAMENU_LIVE_MODE', true),
        'MSLT_MEGAMENU_CATEGORIES' => $categories,
        'MSLT_MEGAMENU_ACCOUNT_EMAIL' => Configuration::get('MSLT_MEGAMENU_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'contact@prestashop.com'),
        'MSLT_MEGAMENU_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD' => Configuration::get('MSLT_MEGAMENU_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null),
    );
}
```

and helper to populate form with values

```
    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
    );

    return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
```

This is the var_dump() when trying to load values from database, for this case my DB value is (1,3,9)

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" }
```

As you can see Configuration::get() only gets the last string value.
Interesting behavior is that when I update the data and stay in the same page, then everything is ok and data is fetched properly, but when I leave module configuration page and comeback, the issue happens. Maybe I am missing some little snippet of code? I am still a newbie. If needed I can provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your specific goal is but in any case it is always convenient to use Prestashop's own functions.
To save and select the configuration variables
eg, save values in json format

```
 Configuration::updateValue('MYVALUES', Tools::jsonEncode(Tools::getValue('MYVALUES')), true );
```

eg, get values

```
Tools::jsonDecode( Configuration::get( 'MYVALUES' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty workaround I found to get imploded values from DB correctly. Maybe someone will use it.

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'configuration WHERE name = "MSLT_MEGAMENU_SELECTED_CAT"';
    $value = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow($sql);
    $selected = explode(',',$value['value']);
```

Comment: Thank you. It will serve as a not recommend code practice